Why is Kraglin allowed to uses telekinesis but not Cosmo?
Kraglin uses telekinesis on Yaka Arrow, but instead of hitting each plate, it pierces  Nebula. Meanwhile, Cosmo uses telekinesis to make a stone hit each plate and land in
front of him:

KRAGLIN: Telekinesis is cheating! That's a stupid little pebble!
I could do that with my dang finger!

Why is Kraglin allowed to use telekinesis  but not Cosmo?

Kraglin's a sore loser.

Yondu claims that the arrow isn't mentally controlled; https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/2e4df765-856a-4aea-bfd9-40121ca06408

The yaka arrow is sound controlled so its kraglin trying to practice whistling which would've seemed(at least to him) harder than making a stone fly by just thinking
